# Hibernate: How to query to an object which it's collection proprty contains a specific value?

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I've got a `Player` Object in which there is a `Collection<Stock>`. I'm willing to write a hibernate query which returns the list of players who have a specific stock (for example stock.symbol="**").

any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

No problem use HQL with join syntax.

see it here

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-joins-forms

For example:

```
Player p join p.myStocks stock where stock.symbol = :symbol
```